# how to configure a downloadable product in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox

i'm quite new to woo commerce and i don't know what i'm doing. hope you guys could help me.

you see i have a product which has a downloadable one. its kinda like a music shop so the attached file would be an mp3 when you configure it on the product. the idea is that while processing thru payment using paypal or after the payment, the user will generate a download link or generate a link in email to download it. now the problem is that when i tried the payment using sandbox or Test Payment Module for Woocommerce plugin, the file is not generating a link to download or a generated link that would go to the email.

i tried this code but its not working.
[Create a downloadable product with audio file in woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602548/create-a-downloadable-product-with-audio-file-in-woocommerce)

any ideas guys? Thank you very much in advance. really appreciate it mates! :)

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce already has this functionality installed. In order to create a downloadable MP3, you have to set your product as a virtual product as well as downloadable. This gives a brief explanation on how to set this up [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/woocommerce-adding-virtual-products-to-your-store--cms-21517).

Once you have done this a section to add your MP3 file will appear.

[image: woocommerce downloadable file]

If the user completes the checkout process and their order has been marked as complete then they should receive an email with a download link to their MP3 file.

[image]

The link should have a few little things in it allowing them to download the file, and only allowing their account to:

`http://www.example.com/?download_file=67&order=wc_order_582db5bbe844f&email={User Email}&key=bc4f3619931ee586ed03d3ed7148a9e7`

This is how I setup my downloadable product using WooCommerce, hope it works the same for you.

Comment: Thanks but i want it to see for my self mate. i tried using paypal sandbox but i cant see the link. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Would you like to see the link in the admin section or on the admin email? Which PayPal sandbox details are you using?

Comment: Also is the order completed upon purchase?

Comment: hey there mate. actually i have no idea. i just wanted to receive the download link to prove that its working. the sandbox i'm using is my pay pal and the order is completed upon purchase. after that i didn't receive any email. :( Thank you very much for helping a newbie like me. really appreciate it.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response, that is strange. Did you check the spam for the email? I just did a test on my side with the same setup and I received the email. Also a quick thought, just check your WooCommerce settings that the purchase emails are being sent to the correct accounts.

Comment: hey mate. its fine. don't stress it out. :) anyways yeah maybe you're right. but i also received the mail but the problem is that i didn't received the downloaded part after the payment.